# Kendo UI Grid refresh icon also has text with Refresh set to true

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

We did an upgrade from 20161.226 to 2017.1.223 and we've encountered a small bug. Everything seems to be working fine except for the refresh icon when paging is enabled. The word "refresh" is being rendered with the icon as shown in the picture (relevant markup below).

Of course we can get rid of this but I'm assuming something went wrong in our upgrade process. Does anyone have a direction they can point us in to get rid of this issue?

```
<a title="Refresh" class="k-pager-refresh k-link" href="/products">
   <span class="k-icon k-i-refresh">Refresh</span>
</a>
```

Comment: i do not see that in the production version see this example http://dojo.telerik.com/odumU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we found a temporary solution while we decide if we want to do a root cause diagnosis. For anyone who is having this issue, we are using razor templates  and MVC 5.

We changed this:

```
.Pageable(pages =>
{
     pages.Refresh(true));
     pages.PageSizes(true);
})
```

to this:

```
.Pageable(pages =>
{
    pages.Refresh(true).Messages(m => m.Refresh(string.Empty));
    pages.PageSizes(true);
})
```

It seems like exposing the Refresh function solved this issue.

**EDIT:**

Root cause: DLL mismatch. The project was referencing 2016.1.226 instead of the 2017.1.223 version of the Kendo.Mvc DLL. Exposing the Refresh function no longer sets the text.

Comment: That is interesting. +1 Did you let Telerik know the issue?